# nginx-quic php able to access last set cookie only

Tags: php, nginx, quic, http3

I implemented nginx-quic using the steps at
https://quic.nginx.org/readme.html

The page is validating http3 quic at https://http3check.net and https://gf.dev/http3-test.

The page elements show h3 protocol in developer tools network tab.

In a test.php page, I have set 3 php cookies like this:

```
<?php
$q=setcookie('test1', 'content1', time()+315360000, '/', '', true, true);
$q=setcookie('test2', 'content2', time()+315360000, '/', '', true, true);
$q=setcookie('test3', 'content3', time()+315360000, '/', '', true, true);
?>
```

In test2.php in the same domain and same directory, I tried to access the cookies:

```
<?php
var_dump($_COOKIE);
?>
```

It is showing only the last set cookie:

```
 array(1) { ["test3"]=> string(8) "content3" }
```

All the three cookies are showing in developer tools.

Javascript is able to read all the three cookies:

```
<script>
var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
console.log('c='+decodedCookie);
</script>
```

If I use nginx http2, php is able to access all the three cookies.

But, If I use nginx http3, php is able to access only the last cookie.

I am using php81-php-fpm in linux server.